# Does Japan have 1.5 million people with severe social withdrawal?

Tags: psychology, japan

*[Hikokomiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikikomori)* is a Japanese concept of severe social withdrawal:

> The Japanese Ministry of Health, Labour, and Welfare defines hikikomori as a condition in which the affected individuals refuse to leave their parents' house, do not work or go to school and isolate themselves away from society and family in a single room for a period exceeding six months.

In April, 2023, [*The Japan Times* reported](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2023/04/01/national/hikikomori-numbers-pandemic/)

> An estimated 1.46 million working-age people in Japan are living as hikikomori (social recluses), a survey by the Cabinet Office showed Friday.

[*Indian Express*](https://indianexpress.com/article/lifestyle/health/hikikomori-japan-1-5-million-people-social-isolation-mental-health-8543799/) and [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/apr/03/japan-says-15-million-people-living-as-recluses-after-covid) also reported the claim.

I find that number to be extreme. [Japan has a population around [123 million](https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/japan-population/) people.]

Does Japan have such a high number of people with severe social withdrawal?

Comment: That looks like a reliable source and a quick Google search seems to more or less support  the numbers. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hikikomori , https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyt.2022.1065304/full#:~:text=They%20reported%20a%20prevalence%20estimate,manic%2C%20and%20hypomanic%20episodes). ) What exactly are you skeptical about other than "the number sounds big to me?"

Comment: To give more context, this [Statistical Handbook of Japan 2022](https://www.stat.go.jp/english/data/handbook/c0117.htm) states that the *working age* population is about 75 million. So 1.5 million alleged *working age* recluses is a much higher proportion than of the whole population – about 1:50 as opposed to 1:84.

Comment: It's [based](https://www.asiapacific.ca/publication/2-percent-japanese-labour-force-modern-day-recluses) on self-reports. The definition is also supposed to exclude people with other mental illness like schizophrenia, but in the case of self-reports, who knows, maybe people would be less willing to report this other stuff...

Comment: FWTW, this [study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352853218300877) using the Japanese scale/def, found the prevalence to be 1.8% in Australia and 1.4% in the US. It was based on a smaller sample though. Search for HSWS (=  Hikikomori Social Withdrawal Scale) therein for the figures. One interesting point is that in those two countries the numbers are hugely biased by prevalence among females, unlike in Japan.

Comment: An answer that avoids reliance on self-reporting could be helpful.  Self-report studies for low-prevalence responses can be pretty dubious since there're a lot of potential explanations for why, say, [~7% of adults might respond that chocolate-milk comes from brown-cows](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38705/).